# Is it bad practice to have independent Django applications to handle simple one-file components?

Tags: python, django

I've been reading about good practices regarding Django projects management. As I understand, is good to:

- Split the project into multiple small applications with specific responsibilities.
- Always code thinking in redistributable components.

The second point has become quite important to me since I usually work on more than one project. So whenever I can, I modularize my components into installable packages which I can later reuse.

The question is... to what extend is this a good practice? how should I handle very simple components which are also highly reusable by other applications?

An example would be a simple reusable templatetag, which may be 40~60 lines of code + tests. If it doesn't do any project-specific operations, I don't see it fitting on any of my project apps, but I also find it to be too small to have an application on its own. Is it?

Comment: For small ones, why not a "utils" app that collects them?

Answer (score 0):

I've been do django projects for 4 years. And all I've got from all projects is few ContextProcessors.

> If it doesn't do any project-specific operations, I don't see it fitting on any of my project apps, but I also find it to be too small to have an application on its own. Is it?

Just look at this like it's always project-specified until you need it in another project. So my answer is:
Write what you want and how you want. If you need stuff in other place then you'll separate it from project. Don't optimize prematurely.